# No Watchlist matches the given query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Trying to add an item to my watchlist suddenly started returning an error

> No Watchlist matches the given query.

Here is what my code looks like.

**models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name="product_name")
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name="product description")
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", verbose_name="image", blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=True)
    initial_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="auction_owner", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Listing, null=True, related_name="watchlist_item")
```

**views.py**

```
def add_to_watchlist(request, item_id):
item = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=item_id)
user_watchlist = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, user=request.user)
user_watchlist.items.add(item)
return redirect("watchlist")
```

**urls.py**

```
path("add_to_watchlist/<int:item_id>", views.add_to_watchlist, name="add_to_watchlist"),
```

**template**

```
<div class="btn-groups">
      {% if listing in watchlist_items %}
      <a href="{% url 'remove_from_watchlist' item_id=listing.id %}" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"><button type = "button" class = "add-cart-btn">remove from watchlist</button></a>
      {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'add_to_watchlist' item_id=listing.id %}" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"><button type = "button" class = "add-cart-btn">add to watchlist</button></a>
      {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because for that user, no `Watchlist` was added *yet*, you can create one if missing with:

```
def add_to_watchlist(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=item_id)
    user_watchlist, __ = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user_watchlist.items.add(item)
    return redirect('watchlist')
```

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls. Some browsers look for
> links and exhaustively already cache the responses of such links, so these might
> trigger such views with side-effects.

Comment: Am getting another error.    'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @OgbonnaEchefunachukwu: you assign the result to `user_watchlist, __`, see edit.